# Extracting a field from a path

Tags: regex

SPLUNK REGEX

we have some data that contains a hierarchy of folders that we want to extract from the source path, the raw data looks like this :

source= /usr/local/intranet/areas/ua1/output/MUN

we would like to create 2 Splunk inline regex to extract the "intranet" and the "output"

Can someone please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the kind of job you want to solve with regex, to be honest. You're probably better off string parsing it by splitting then selecting what you need from the array?

Regardless, you could likely just do something like this:

Input:
`/usr/local/intranet/areas/ua1/output/MUN`

Regex:
`(?:\/.+?){2}\/([^\/]+)(?:\/.+?){2}\/([^\/]+)`

Then group 1 will match `intranet` and group 2 will match `output`.

- `(?:\/.+?){2}` - Match a forward-slash followed by whatever characters twice. So this matches `/usr/local`.
- `\/([^\/]+)` - Match a forward-slash, then in a group match the contents of the section until the next slash. This matches `/intranet` but stores `intranet` in group 1.

Then we just repeat this to get the next segment you want as well.

If you need 2 separate patterns or want to match *only* the relevant part instead of putting them in groups, then like this, assuming the global modifier is disabled:

- `(?<=\/)[^\/]+(?=(?:\/[^\/]+){4}$)` - To match `intranet`.
- `(?<=\/)[^\/]+(?=\/[^\/]+$)` - To match `output`

This one uses a look-behind `(?<=…)` and look-ahead `(?=…)` instead of matching, so it's not included in the final result, no groups needed. Otherwise, it follows mostly the same logic.